# Can I use SO_REUSEADDR and SO_EXCLUSIVEADDRUSE option in sametime?

Tags: c++

i starting a server programming.
    and i have some question...
    i try make a one device multiple server
    so i used reuse_addr option for "address is already use" issue.
    but i want show error when two server use same address and same port
    so i tried to use SO_EXCLUSIVEADDRUSE option
    but it return -1..
    how should i do to do it

```
io_service svc;
tcp::acceptor a(svc);

boost::system::error_code ec;
int one = 1;
a.open(tcp::v4(), ec);

a.set_option(tcp::acceptor::reuse_address(true), ec);
int eb = setsockopt(a.native_handle(), SOL_SOCKET, SO_EXCLUSIVEADDRUSE,
        (char*)&optval, sizeof(optval));

if (eb < 0) {
        std::cout << "errorcode : " << eb;
        return true; }

a.bind({ tcp::v4(), port }, ec);
if (ec != 0)
{
    std::cout << "Port " << 44000 << " is in use\n";
    return true;
}
```

Comment: i want avoid two listening server same port and address

Comment: If you don't want it shared why are you using SO_REUSEADDR? It doesn't make sense. Remove it. See [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/windows/desktop/WinSock/so-exclusiveaddruse).

Comment: I heard that when I restarted the server, the kernel had a port with time_wait status
So I get an error " address is already use " when I bind again.